# AutomationElement: cached element (via GetCachedChildren) to "live" element

Tags: c#, caching, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I have a ComboBox containing a list (which is standard for a combobox) that has a lot of elements - more than 100. I want to find certain entries to select them. To find the entries, I compare a given pattern to the name of each element.

For performance reasons (more than 100 elements), I am using a CacheRequest on the parent with a scope of all children, so I can nicely and very quickly go through all the children and find the correct index of the child I want to select.

Here comes the problem: I have the correct index I want, I also have the cached AutomationElement, but since I specified AutomationElementMode.None in the CacheRequest (I still have to test if it gives an impact on performance), I seem not to be able to convert the cached element to one I can use for future calls (a "live" element).

I tried conversion via NativeWindowHandle (since there is a function AutomationElement.FromWindowHandle), but the handle seems to be 0, so this is no way.

I also have not tried to use a cached SelectionPattern yet - since the ComboBoxes are sometimes custom built, I don't know whether that would work in all cases though (if any at all).

I have the child-index, I can get all the values I could cache - how can I get a working/live AutomationElement of the cached element?

Thanks
Andreas

(using C# on Windows 7 64 with a win32 application (as automation target), though that should not make a big difference)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the child text that you need in addition to the index?  If so, would it be possible to send the child text to the combo box as if a user were typing to select the child that you need instead of trying to get an automation element?

There is always the IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern to fall back on, but I think that is only in the core API and not the client (AutomationElement).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How do you get that interace? Is ther a conversion from UIAtuomation to an object implementing that interface?

Comment: Yes, but only using the unmanaged API, which is better, in my opinion.  Read more here:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/thread/c3f142e1-0624-4ec5-a313-482e72d5454d   (As far as I can tell the IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern is not part of the managed code).  Let me know if you want to give the unmanaged a try and I can add to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, using AutomationElementMode.None seems to have been not the best idea. The time a cache requests takes seems to be only marginally influenced by whether you request a live element and how many properties you request. (Correct me if I am wrong - I did not test systematically but got that feeling recently when toying around with some options on my cache request.)

It seems to be mostly influenced by the number of UI elements you request in the first place.

So I could request a live link in the first place.

That makes me wonder now whether access through some Win32SDK function would be any faster..